# Ruby: how to do scp within ssh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I am trying to login machine B and then copy a file from machine A to machine B. The goal is to directly transfer file from A to B, which I don't want to use a third machine in the middle. But I find it hard to accomplish in Ruby. Here is the starting code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

cmd = 'scp -v -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@machineA:~/some.tar.gz .'
Net::SSH.start("machineB", "user", :password => "pwd") do |session|
  session.exec!(cmd) do |channel, stream, data|
    channel.send_data "pwd"
  end
end
```

The idea is that I first ssh to machine B, then try to run scp from it. The first challenge is that I cannot feed password to scp (no tty as ssh complains).

Is there a way to generate an Net::SCP object from Net::SSH?

Thanks.

Comment: is your script to be run on machineA?

Comment: Is a password a must-have, or is it possible that you could use SSH keys instead of a pasword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answering your question:
Apparently yes, you can pass an ssh session as an argument.

```
scp = Net::SCP.new(session)
```

That's actually what `Net::SCP.start` does https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp/blob/master/lib/net/scp.rb#L202

If your script runs on machineA can't you just do:

```
Net::SCP.upload!("machineB", "user",
  "~/some.tar.gz",
  "~/.",
  ssh: { password: "pwd" })
```

Comment: That's probably not what I mean. This scp is, I guess, still connected to machine B. But I want is from B to A.

Comment: The same issue here, I need to ssh to machine A first. If there is some like, Net::SSH.start( ... A ...).scp.upload( ... B ...), then that would be excellent.

Comment: With scp you can download and upload files. You dont need to SSH into B. Just run SCP from A to send the file to B

Comment: My goal is not to login A to run the script. I am organizing a distributed testing. It is hard for me to login each machine to run the script. I prefer more just stay at one machine and automatically start scripts on other machines.